# Is there Any Documentation yet for the new Developer APIs of iOS 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, ios5

I´m playing a little bit with the New iOS 5 SDK and Xcode 4.3.3 and found an app template for a page based application. But I didn´t found any documentation about that in the developer reference. Are there any other sources in the moment?

Comment: Pretty sure not anywhere else as the documentation is all under NDA.

Comment: This question is of only passing interest (hint: "at the moment" is in the question), so is too localized for Stack Overflow. Once iOS 5 is public, there will most likely be plenty of documentation and samples and walkthroughs to go around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start here: [What's New in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html)
It is a good overview and it has links to additional docs.

Comment: -1 This is covered by NDA (it's inaccessible to non-members) and should not be posted publicly.

Comment: Can you point me to a post in meta discouraging posting information that breaks a contract with a 3rd party? I found the opposite: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49009/as-an-ipad-iphone-ipod-touch-developer-what-cant-i-ask-or-answer-on-stack-overf

Comment: thx a lot ... ok th..ank god i have access to the Reference

Comment: I'll take away the downvote, but if you're a paid developer I think it's a better idea to play safe regarding these things...